# Event Tag - Google Tag Manager + Firebase + Google Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to make a Tag in Tag Manager that will be fired (triggered) when certain firebase event happens and then send this information to a property in Google Analytics.
The question is:

Which fields in this tags are necessary for me to see the event in Google Analytics?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When integrating Firebase + Tag Manager and GA first you need the minimum fields for an event in GA (Look for the documentation) and second based on my experience if you want to send values captured from firebase ALWAYS give the parameter in GTM a default value because if the value is empty the event wont fire.

Comment: The crazy thing is that i can see the event being fire from the monitor in android studio, but i'm not seeing the event getting to the property in GA, 
i made one tag for screenviews and that is working just right!